# Converting JavaScript date to JSON/.net date format

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I have a regular date i.e.:

```
 date=  03-12-2014
```

I need to convert it to JSON or .Net date format. Like this:

```
 "\/Date(1283219926108)\/"
```

I can see a lot of posts that go from JSON date to regular date but not backward. Please let me know how to do it. I am hoping for some easy JavaScript way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know/Have you tried `(new Date).getTime()`

That's the most easiest "cross-browser" solution I know of ...

In your situation something like:

```
(new Date(date)).getTime()
```

It's a little bit vague to see what the difference is between .net- and javascript code.
Can you point it out more clearly?

Comment: I believe the difference is very little JSON date is like "/Date(12383219926108)/" Which is fine cause I can always add the other slashes. Problem is I have datepicker date which inputs date in a field which is in regular format when i submit it using JSON it wont take it, it needs in its native format

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this little jQuery file. https://gist.github.com/gigi81/1868478

It does date parsing for .NET.